# shouldComponentUpdate and child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a couple wrapper components which dynamically calculate the size and position they need to be. Normally this works and performs great with `shouldComponentUpdate`, but as soon as I add children inside these components I can no longer use this method. Why? Because if i return 'false' for the wrapper needing an update... the children never get updated themselves :(

Example JSX:

`<ReactWrapper>
  <ChildElement/>
</ReactWrapper>`

Is there any good way around this? Only idea I have is to add a new method shouldUpdateChildren like this other question detailed: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/shouldcomponentupdate-and-children/2055

Comment: Can you show code of the logic you are using? Why do you need to `return false` in `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Comment: Simply because it's not necessary to run any calculations for the x, y, width, height of the component. Why recalc when you know you don't have to?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the following to yor shoudComponentUpdate:

`this.props.children !== prevProps.children //according to below the thread`

`this.props.children !== nextProps.children //according to me`

Here is an interesting thread on this:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12185#issuecomment-364531032

I do wonder why Dan calls it `prevProps`. To my knowledge, shouldComponentUpdate receives `nextProps`, `nextState` and `nextContext`. At least in React Native. Is this different in regular React?

**Edit:**

I read your linked thread and I think I understand your case better now.

I've a similar case where I have a local `calcParams()`-function in the parent component which does not need to be called for every child update.

I simply do a check in the start of `calcParams` to see if any props that would affect the calculations are changed. I store the result of the calculations in `this.calculatedParams`, i.e. not in `this.state.calculatedParams` as this.state should only be set via setState().

I'll leave my original answer above, because It's kind of related.